# Integral evaluation error

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages, assumptions

I have the following integral that I wish to evaluate using Mathematica:

`Assuming[{x > 0, y > 0}, NIntegrate[(x - d)/(2 σ^2)Exp[(I k x^2)/(2 R)- (x - d)^2/(4 σ^2)] NIntegrate[Exp[(I k y^2)/(2 R) - (I k y x)/R], {y, -0.5, 0.5}], {x, -0.01, 0.01}]]`

For which *Mathematica* returns with the error: *'The integrand $e^\left({\frac{-I x y}{10} + \frac{I y^2}{20}}\right)$ has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{-0.5,0.0}}'*

All coefficients have been initialised to values: $d = 1, R = 10, k=1$. Are there any tips that I could try to evaluate this?

Comment: `i` is not `I` which is  (`Sqrt[-1]`)

Comment: The `Assuming[]` is useless here; apart from @chuy's prescription, you need to specify numerical values for your parameters to get something out of `NIntegrate[]`.

Comment: `@Guess who it is` I already have all of the values specified: `$d = 1$, $R = 10$, $k=1$`. The only variables not initialised are x and y since these are the integration variables. Also in the script, I have `:ii:` which suitably yields the imaginary unit, `I`. The error still persists.

Comment: Okay, have you tried putting it all into a single `NIntegrate[]`? Like, `NIntegrate[(* stuff *), {x, -0.01, 0.01}, {y, -0.5, 0.5}]`?

Comment: Ah never mind... the MWE of your problem really is: `NIntegrate[ x NIntegrate[x y, {y, 0, 1}], {x, 0, 1}]`

Comment: Make sure `\[Sigma]` has a numerical value and add `Evaluated -> False` (or define the inner integral as `f[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Exp[(I k y^2)/(2 R) - (I k y x)/R], {y, -0.5, 0.5}]` to prevent symbolic evaluation.

Answer (score 3):

Problems of this sort are posted from time to time in Mathematica SE.  Multiple instances of `Nintegrate` are nested one inside another, and an inner integrand contains one of the outer variables of integration.  And, from the point of view of the inner `NInterate`, the outer variable is undefined.  (Chuy noted this in a comment above.)  The solution is to have one multi-dimensional `NIntegrate`.

```
d = 1; R = 10; k = 1; σ = 1;
NIntegrate[(x - d)/(2 σ^2) Exp[(I k x^2)/(2 R) - (x - d)^2/(4 σ^2)] 
  Exp[(I k y^2)/(2 R) - (I k y x)/R], {y, -0.5, 0.5}, {x, -0.01, 0.01}]
(* -0.00778772 - 0.000032462 I *)
```

As it happens, replacing the inner `NIntegrate` by `Integrate` also works in this case.

```
NIntegrate[(x - d)/(2 σ^2) Exp[(I k x^2)/(2 R) - (x - d)^2/(4 σ^2)]
  Integrate[Exp[(I k y^2)/(2 R) - (I k y x)/R], {y, -0.5, 0.5}], {x, -0.01, 0.01}]
```

of course, giving the same answer.

**Addendum**

As noted by Guess who it is, `Assuming[{x > 0, y > 0}, ...]` is unnecessary, although harmless.  I have deleted it from the answer.

Comment: I'm still confused as to why there's an `Assuming[]` for the dummy variables…

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. There need not be.  I was not paying attention.  Thanks.